# Python pywin32 running application in its directory

Tags: python, pywin32

I am using Python pywin32 for running application. The problem is I need to be in root directory of application exe file to successfully run it. Lets take for example that we want to run notepad++.exe in application root. In CMD I tried this and it worked:

```
C:\>(cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++" && notepad++.exe)
```

But if running it in python with shell.Run:

```
import win32com.client
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run('(cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++" && notepad++.exe)')
```

Returns exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<COMObject WScript.Shell>", line 2, in Run
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147024894), None)
```

Which when decoding it:

```
import win32api
e_msg = win32api.FormatMessage(-2147024894)
```

Strangely says:

```
'The system cannot find the file specified.\r\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

```
shell.Run('cmd /K (cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++" && notepad++.exe)')
```

or, even more simply:

```
shell.Run('cmd /K cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++" && notepad++.exe')
```